# Sabre Profile Error

Tags: sabre, profiles

When I transfer a profile to a PNR, I am continually getting an error saying:

```
"7014: Profile was partially copied to PNR. An error has been encountered.

Details: FMT: PC/CCC
.FRMT.NOT ENT BGNG WITH PC/CC"
```

I saw online that this could have to do with being a preferred customer? I don't know how to access that part of the profile.

Comment: Seems like the profile field filled with PC/CCC has a symbol which is not allowed in this command. Which property of the profile is not copied?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar Sabre Format - CC/PC - that may be valid. It looks to me like there is a format that is in your Sabre profile (either at the corporate or traveler level) that is sending "PC/CCC" instead. Maybe that was a typo when building the profile?

Regardless of where it came from, and assuming you have access to the admin side of the Sabre Profiles, the simplest solution is probably to remove the offending format from the Sabre Profile. I would expect to find it in the "Other PNR Move Data (3, 5, 5‡)" section of the corporate or traveler level profile.

If you don't have access to the Sabre Profile, it should still copy the rest of the profile data when copying, so perhaps you can simply ignore the error programmatically?